# Are any species of life now increasing besides humans?

Tags: species

I see how many species are growing extinct, but what species (excluding humans) are increasing in number?

Comment: Chickens. Dogs probably. Lots of others. Even some populations of Tigers are increasing in number thanks to conservation efforts. The question is too big to answer completely. If you have a species in mind then I'd as about that instead.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, many are, especially ones associated with humans and human-generated structures and conditions (e.g., trash, global warming, water nitrification). Some hitchike on subjects of human commerce (e.g., potted plants, tires) and we tend to call them called "invasive species."

Some prominent examples in North America are the European starling, rock dove, house sparrow, domesticated cat, wild horse (mustang), tumbleweed, kudzu, many eucalyptus species, purple loosestrife, garlic mustard, zebra mussel, Argentine ant, fire ant, Japanese beetle, Asian long-horn beetle, Phytophora infestans, etc. One of my favorite examples, and a rather odd one, is the nine-banded armadillo.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sfsu.edu](http://online.sfsu.edu/bholzman/courses/Fall99Projects/armadillo2.jpg))</sub>

Some of these species are increasing in abundance at the cost of other species, increasing the pace of extinction.

http://www.nature.nps.gov/biology/invasivespecies/

Comment: You might want to find a *slightly* more updated graphic, seeing as the 1982 territories are *projected*. Try Wikipedia.

Comment: Sure, but I will not find one this beautiful. Also, the projections held very well.